# Selecting a descendant in jQuery if I have a reference to an item already

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><div>test</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>test</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a reference to `#myTable` in the variable `$myTable`.

How can I select all descendant `div` tags without using the string `#myTable` again (i.e. use the `$myTable` object only)?

To clarify, assuming this example worked:

```
$('#myTable div')
```

... it fails to meet my criteria, since I don't want to retype `#myTable`.

Additionally, I'd prefer not having to specify each parent in the hierarchy like this:

```
$myTable.children('tr').children('td').children('div')
```

I tried using

```
$myTable.children('div')
```

... but it seems to only select immediate children, which the `div` elements are not.

I want to use something terse like this:

```
$myTable.descendants('div')
```

Comment: You have a typo in your table id -- the markup shouldn't include the `#` sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `find` function in jQuery.

```
$myTable.find('div');
```

Alternatively you can specify the scope like this:

```
$('div', $myTable);
```

both should return the same set

Answer (score 4):

The [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function does exactly what you want.

`$myTable.find('div');`

Answer (score 1):

You might have trouble testing the suggested solutions because you have included the "#" in your id attribute.  It should be:

```
<table id="myTable">
```

And you can just use `$('div', $myTable)` to select the descendant divs.

[Check out solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Jxh9J/)

Comment: While this is true, it's worth noting that jQuery takes `$('div', $myTable)` and calls `$($(myTable)).find('div')`: "Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span')." [Taken from the API reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).